# Issue with Blazor Server App with dynamic OpenIdConnect for multi tenancy

Tags: blazor, openid-connect, multi-tenant

We have a blazor server app that uses MSFT OpenIdConnect with IOptionsMonitor and IConfigureOptions to handle a multi tenant system based on a tenant name in the url

the app uses Cognito as the IDP and redirects the login to the proper cognito tenant based on the tenant.

it normally works fine getting the OpenIdConnectOptions for the tenant and handles the login.

But sometimes it fails and at that point it will return the incorrect OpenIdConnectOptions for a different tenant for one tenant. other tenants on the same server still work but the one that is broken can only be fixed by recycling the app pool

hard to debug of course because it only happens sometimes on the production server

Any idea what i could be looking into to figure out why this happens?

tried adding logs to the OpenIdConnectOptions Get method which is i guess were the issue happens

seems like maybe somehow the dictionary gets messed up or something but really not sure.